# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x16e9900) to 'NSArray' (0x16e96f8)

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a project and have reached a stage where I want to display data from a web service in a table view. I am using the Alamofire library but when I build my project I am getting the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x16e9900) to 'NSArray' (0x16e96f8).

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class TestingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   var listData : [[String : AnyObject]] = [[String : AnyObject]]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        let url : URL = URL(string : "some url")!
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                self.listData = response.result.value as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }

        })
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

The json data is as follows:

```
    {
  "oscBalances": [
    {
      "walletName": "Main Balance",
      "walletBalance": -0.548927,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 4607186400000
    },

    {
      "walletName": "Gprs_bundle",
      "walletBalance": 0,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 1472853599000
    },
    {
      "walletName": "Go_SVB1",
      "walletBalance": 0,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 1480738710000
    },

    {
      "walletName": "Go_SVB1",
      "walletBalance": 0,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 1480738710000
    },

    {
      "walletName": "night_bundle",
      "walletBalance": 245.66,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 1486147937000
    },    {
      "walletName": "night_bundle",
      "walletBalance": 245.66,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 1486147937000
    },
    {
      "walletName": "Daily_Data1",
      "walletBalance": 510437397772.4562,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 1487250499000
    },
    {
      "walletName": "Go_SVB1",
      "walletBalance": 0,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 1480738710000
    }
 ],
  "pcrfBalances": [
    {
      "svrName": "Weekly Whatsapp",
      "quotaBalance": 174.92578125,
      "quotaConsumption": 5.07421875,
      "expiryDate": 1488204496000
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to display the walletName, walletBalance and walletBalanceExpiryDate for the OCS balances and for pcrfBalances i want to display svrName, quotaBalance, quotaConsumption, expiryDate

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: on the line with code below:

     self.listData = response.result.value as! [[String : AnyObject]]

Comment: `response.result.value` is a Dictionary, not an array of dictionary as you casted it.

Comment: @tapiwatakaindisa May be you are getting JOSN with top level as dictionary not array. Can you show your json,

Comment: what would be the best way to cast it

Comment: @tapiwatakaindisa Show us you json structure then we can help you.

Comment: {
  "oscBalances": [
    {
      "walletName": "Main Balance",
      "walletBalance": -0.548927,
      "walletBalanceExpiryDate": 4607186400000
    }

Comment: Directedly to use NSDictionary() rather than [String : AnyObject] between views.

Answer (score 3):

With that error "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x16e9900) to 'NSArray' (0x16e96f8)." for line :

```
 self.listData = response.result.value as! [[String : AnyObject]]
```

The original Dict object is this here:

```
[String : AnyObject]
```

versus the Array of Dictionaries (That is throwing the error)

```
[[String : AnyObject]]
```

So the line should succeed like so:

```
 self.listData = response.result.value as! [String : AnyObject]
```

**Updated**
 @rmaddy made a good point. Also from the JSON you shared, it looks as though your array you are trying to access is within the dictionary.

so:

```
if let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
 self.listData = dictionary["oscBalances"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
}
```

Should return your desired list data

Comment: The last suggestion in this answer may allow the code to compile and run but it doesn't mean it is correct. The dictionary value may contain the desired array. The OP hasn't provided enough information to know.

Comment: @rmaddy i have added the json data and what i really want to display

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from:

```
self.listData = response.result.value as! [[String : AnyObject]]
```

Since the error is complaining that you are trying to convert a dictionary to an array, it clearly means that `response.result.value` is a dictionary. So your attempt to cast it as an array is failing.

Perhaps the dictionary contains the desired array. You need to dig into the dictionary and get whatever data you want. Or change your cast to be an appropriate dictionary.

A more concrete answer will require you to edit your question with more specific details about the data you are getting and the data you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JSON data you pasted in there, it seems like you are trying to access the `oscBalances` list, so your code should look like this:

```
if let dict = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject], let list = dict["oscBalances"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
    self.listData = list
}
```

Or if you really want to force cast the data (which will crash if something unexpected shows up in the JSON), it'd look like this:

```
self.listData = (response.result.value as! [String : AnyObject])["oscBalances"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
```

The first way is safer.